# Basic PHP number calculation

Tags: php

Say I have the following:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    // get the sum of all numbers
}
```

Basically, I want to calculate **1+2+3+4+5=?** What's the easiest way to do this?

Comment: `echo array_sum(range(1, 5));`

Comment: you can also use the formula `n*(n+1)/2`, in this case `n=5`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$j=0;
for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    // get the sum of all numbers

   $j += $i;
}

echo $j; //print the sum of all numbers
```

Comment: Could simply have `$j += $i;` in the for loop instead.

Comment: Better! A simpler concatenation compared to before :)

Answer (score 2):

or you can do this simple mathematical formula `1+2+....+n=((n+1)*n)/2`